# Replacing the upstairs toilet with a floating one; The basement ceiling is open right below the toilet; Should I call the plumber now for upstairs?

Tags: plumbing

Consider you have the layout in the first picture and consider that I want to replace the upstairs toilet with a floating one. For that to happen the plumber will have to do something with the drain for the old toilet and then cut the main stack (the blueish big vertical pipe) and then connect the drain for the new toilet somewhere there.

Right now I am renovating the downstairs bathroom and I am dealing with an issue I just posted previously about, around here in this forum. I just realized that the plumber that will do the upstairs work might need to work from below to do a better job. You can see what it looks like from below in the second picture. The drain that needs to be removed is connected to the main stack just above the 10" mark on the tape, you can guess it there. What is the standard procedure in these situations, what does the plumber do with the old toilet drain and when should I call the guy?

It might be too early from the upstairs bathroom perspective since I have not started the work there and I have not removed the horrible subway tiles that I currently have there. Do I have to call the plumber now? I would prefer not to but I am asking just because this is the last moment when I can still do that and allow him to work from below if he has to

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably have like $10,000 worth the copper in your home. Haha, anyway, you should probably call your plumber and ask what we would prefer. After all, he's doing the work. 

Comment: I cut and set aside a pipe that was a dry vent that was used for a sink that is not there anymore, it was left in the wall. How much do you think it is worth ? it is like an 8'x2" piece of pipe

Comment: I do not have a plumber yet and I do not want to commit one this early since I do not even have that floating toilet.

Comment: You don't need to commit to one. They will come out and consult and make a plan with the generator contractor. Are you using a GC?

Comment: Nope DIY but the above is too much for me

Comment: @DrSparks Pure copper is worth about four dollars per pound, scrap copper considerably less.

Comment: I would definitely get a seasoned plumber to take a look at these photos and ask their opinion on closing the downstairs access    I would think they will want full access to the sewer pipe especially since it is copper and much more difficult to work with.

Comment: Ask a plumber now to look at it.  They might say they do all the work from above, but if work has to be, or is easier from below(time is money), then you do not want the new ceiling needing to be torn down.

Comment: Also a floating toilet requires significant framing modifications and reinforcements.  You want a qualified framing carpenter to be ready to assist if the plumber balks at doing the wood work

Comment: Good point. The wall it goes into is a partition wall not a load bearing one and as far as I can see in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HRQKfx6j00&ab_channel=ThisOldHouse the only thing special about it is the space between the studs. I think I can handle that

Comment: This video is very detailed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0T6hTTvpgA&ab_channel=TOTOUSA Yet I have to find what that shows how you install one when there is an old one in place